# Defining a domain using libvirt-go bindings

Tags: libvirt

I am trying to use the libvirt-go api binding and following the example snippet [here](https://www.berrange.com/posts/2017/01/05/announce-new-libvirt-project-go-xml-parser-model/), have so far populated the domcfg variable thus:

```
domcfg := &libvirtxml.Domain{
        Type: "kvm",
        Name: "demo",
        Memory: &libvirtxml.DomainMemory{
            Value:    4096,
            Unit:     "MB",
            DumpCore: "on"},
        VCPU: &libvirtxml.DomainVCPU{
            Value: 1},
        CPU: &libvirtxml.DomainCPU{
            Mode: "host-model"},
        Devices: &libvirtxml.DomainDeviceList{
            Disks: []libvirtxml.DomainDisk{
                Source: &libvirtxml.DomainDiskSource{
                    File: &DomainDiskSourceFile{
                        File: "./vm.qcow2"}},
                BackingStore: &DomainDiskBackingStore{
                    BackingStore: &DomainDiskBackingStore{

                    }
                }}}
```

I am not sure I am completely on the right path so, is this the right way to define the variable before marshalling to xml? Also I find the struct defined at https://godoc.org/github.com/libvirt/libvirt-go-xml#DomainDiskBackingStore specifically the BackingStore field which seems to be a pointer to itself, is it possible to embed a field in a struct which is the struct definition itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is the right approach to defining a XML config inline in Go. To define the domain you can then do

```
xml, err := domcfg.Marshal()
if err != nil {
   ...
}

dom, err := conn.DomainDefineXML(xml)
if err != nil {
   ...
}
```

The disk backing store is a way to provide information about the full disk chain. Generally you can leave this set to nil because libvirt will automatically detect the chain for you. There can be multiple levels of backing chain, hence why the struct contains a field with its own type again.

Comment: I seem to be getting an error in the source field undefined: Source
cannot use *libvirtxml.DomainDiskSource literal (type *libvirtxml.DomainDiskSource) as type libvirtxml.DomainDisk in array or slice literal

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any method defined for conn.DomainDefine, did you mean conn.DomainDefineXML?

Comment: Yes, DomainDefineXML